# What's the usage or purpose of Orbeon HTTP session

Tags: orbeon

What's the purpose of Orbeon HTTP session? Is it possible we remove the session to make it stateless session?

Comment: I hope my answer below helps. But I'm curious: why would you like to get rid of the session?

Comment: We have stateless Single Page Application that call to jsp(which use orbeon embeded lib to call orbeon). Facing issue after added another orbeon server for high availability. So we wonder if it's because of sticky session issue and if we don't need session, can configure to remove it.

Comment: We had solved our issue by using sticky session to ensure user is forward to the correct orbeon server.

Comment: Yes you must always use sticky sessions with Orbeon Forms. Good to see you managed to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you are filling out a form, the "state" of that form is maintained on the server, and associated with the session. In addition, if the user is authenticated, the servlet container will typically use the session to keep track of who the user is. So, no, you can't do without a session. But sessions can also be relatively short-lived, in the sense that they just need to stick around while users are filling a particular form in their browser.